# LINQ inner query returns null

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have 2 simple lists :

And my code returns null when i try this simple query as this:

```
var linq = from s in mojUser
           from us in mojDev
           // join us in mojUser on s.DeviceId equals us.UserId
           where s.UserId==us.DeviceId
           select new
           {
             user = s.UserMac
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var linq = from s in mojUser
           join us in mojDev on s.UserId equals us.DeviceId
           select new
           {
             user = s.UserMac
           }
```

Comment: Maybe `equals` instead of `==`?

Comment: @SeM That's probably `int` variable, thus using `Equals` would is not necessary.

Comment: The thing is - you can't have `==` in `join`, it will not compile.

Comment: @SeM Yeah... You are right, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: No problem....)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `join` statement;

```
var linq = from s in mojUser
           join us in mojDev on s.UserId==us.DeviceId
           select new
           {
             s.UserMac
           }
```

or using the extension method:

```
   var linq = mojUser.Join(mojDev,
          s => s.UserId,
          us => us.DeviceId,
          (s, us) => new { s.UserMac });
```

Comment: Same thing here, you can't compare keys for equality with `==` inside join clause.

Comment: So basically i have changed call order of my two lists and code works.